# change autorun value in registry using CMD

Tags: registry, autorun

how can I add an entry to the `autorun` registry by using `cmd` or `powershell`?

Assuming that the .exe that i want to start is located in `%userprofile%\desktop`
and the registry entry shall be added to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, what command do I have to enter?

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to add an registry entries using cmd, then the command your looking for is `REG add`

**Syntax:**

```
Add: REG ADD KeyName [{/v ValueName | /ve}] [/t Type] [/f]
Delete: REG DELETE KeyName [{/v ValueName | /ve | /va}] [/f]
```

Your code should look as the following:

```
reg.exe add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /f /v ProgramName /t REG_SZ /d "%userprofile%\desktop\yourfile.exe"
```